# How do I force the column to display in the next row?

Tags: html, css

I have more than five to six column it will increase in the future. I have to display each row with three column. So how do I force the column to display in the next row? I set parent class `display: table` and child class `display:table-cell` because I have to display the equal height of the column.

I am getting the output like this
[image]

I need output like this.
[image]

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 30px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.row { display:table-row;width: 100%; }

li{
  display:table-cell;
  padding:5px;
  background-color: gold;
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <ul class="row">
        <li>Cell 1</li>
        <li>Cell 2</li>
        <li>Cell 3</li>
        <li>Cell 4</li>
        <li>Cell 5</li>
        <li>Cell 6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What your html is thinking right now: "Mhmh, I see a row with a width of 100%, and inside of that 6 list items that have a width of 33%, thats 6 x 33% = 200%.... Wait how do I make this fit inside this 100% width row?".

Comment: @Jeremy, that's correct. what is the way to set it? how can I set to force the column to set only three in each row?

Comment: Since there have to be 3 in a row, I think you have to make (for this example) 2 `<ul class='row'>`'s with each 3 `<li>` items inside of it.

Comment: I'd ditch the table display and just go for flexbox or similar way to organize this view. Display table is a bad choice for non tabular data, as it indicates a certain level of semantic.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this one as well. You can see here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/94mpabvf/3/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.table .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style:none
}

.table .row li {
  background: orange;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid white;
}

.table + .table li {
  background: olive;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <ul class="row">
        <li>Cell 1</li>
        <li>Cell 2</li>
        <li>Cell 3</li>
        <li>Cell 4</li>
        <li>Cell 5</li>
        <li>Cell 6</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="table">
    <ul class="row">
        <li>Cell 1</li>
        <li>Cell 2</li>
        <li>Cell 3</li>
        <li>Cell 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @user9437856 - You should consider reading about Flexbox. You can see it works automatically for both your described usecases (4 columns with a 100% width 4th column, as well as 6 even columns) - without any additional markup or CSS. This is the route I would go with unless I specifically needed [Tabular Data Representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_(information)#Generic_representation).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you'll need to add a `row` wrapper around each set of columns without using a different layout method (such as flexbox).

Since you have a Flexbox answer already (see @Shiva's answer), here's a tabular one with row wrappers and `table-layout: fixed;`. Note I've also changed your `ul` and `li` to `div` to remove some automatic CSS that is applied to list items.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 30px 30px;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.row { display:table-row;width: 100%; }

.cell {
  display:table-cell;
  padding:5px;
  background-color: gold;
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Cell 1</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell 2</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Cell 4</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell 5</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell 6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated:

I still think you should consider a different layout method (such as flexbox) - but if you want to use a CSS table layout with variable width cells, you may want to actually use a `table` instead of emulating one, and making use of the `colspan` attribute. Note this is very oldschool and should hardly be considered useful for an actual layout. If you're showing tabular data, it's fine, but if you are laying out more complex content, look at flex box (an answer has been provided that should work for you) or CSS Grid, or grid frameworks like [Ungrid](http://chrisnager.com/ungrid/).

Regardless, here's a table layout:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 30px 30px;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}


td {
  padding:5px;
  background-color: gold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What If i have only 4 columns because last one getting the 100% background color

Comment: If you're looking for a dynamic layout, look at Flexbox, CSS Grid, or a framework like Ungrid. If you need a rudimentary table, drop the CSS and actually use a table. I've updated the answer to include a table layout like you described.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved using css grid. You may add, as many as possible elements, inside the wrapper div. Moreover, it will be responsive.

```css
body{
  margin:20px;
}
.wrapper{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(3,1fr);
  grid-auto-rows:100px;
  grid-gap:5px;
}
.wrapper > div{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  color:#fff;
  background:#FF8966;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>Cell 1</div>
    <div>Cell 2</div>
    <div>Cell 3</div>
    <div>Cell 4</div>
    <div>Cell 5</div>
    <div>Cell 6</div>
</div>
```